# Biblatex uniquename: spell out full first name

Tags: biblatex

For a paper I am writing, I will have to refer to many Taiwanese authors. As the list of Chinese last names is pretty limited, I quite often have different authors that share the same last name (but different first names) publishing articles/books in the same year.

I have tried several "uniquename" options with biblatex, but none achieved the desired result.

At first I tried:

```
uniquename=false
```

This resulted in the folling inline citation:

> (Chu 1994a, p. 1) and (Chu 1994b, p. 4)

Different authors are assigned "Chu 1994a" and "Chu 1994b", etc. But I would prefer the a, b, c differentiation to be used only "within" the same author, as otherwise it might be misunderstood as me citing two works of the same author.

I then used:

```
uniquename=minfull
```

which results in:

> (T.-t. Chu 1994, p. 1) and (T.-e. Chu 1994, p. 4).

This solves the "a, b, c" problem, but as most Taiwanese authors have a hyphen in their first name, biblatex's procedure to use the initials of the first name results in many "Y.-h.", "Y.-c." and "W.-w." in the text, which I find not pleasing to the eye.

What I would like to achieve is biblatex using normal author-year citations by last name as long as there is no ambiguity (Wu in my example). But if there is an ambiguity, I would like it to spell out the complete first name, not only initials. In the best of all worls, I would even prefer it to cite as "Lastname, Firstname Year", that is:

> (Chu, Test-test 1994) and (Chu, Trial-error 1994)

Is there a way to do this?

Here is my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{uniquename.bib}
@article{chu1994one,
author = {Chu, Test-test},
title = {Title1},
journaltitle = {Journal 1},
year = {1994},
volume = {22},
issue = {5},
pages = {1--2}
}

@article{chu1994two,
author = {Chu, Trial-error},
title = {Title2},
journaltitle = {Journal 2},
year = {1994},
volume = {22},
issue = {5},
pages = {3--4}
}

@article{wu1994one,
author = {Wu, Test-name},
title = {Title3},
journaltitle = {Journal 3},
year = {1994},
volume = {22},
issue = {5},
pages = {5--6}

}
\end{filecontents}



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, uniquename=minfull, bibstyle=authoryear, autocite=inline, backend=biber]
 {biblatex}


\addbibresource{uniquename.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text with a citation \autocite[1]{chu1994one}, and some further text with another citation \autocite[4]{chu1994two}. Some more text with a third citation \autocite[5]{wu1994one}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `volume = {22}, issue = {5},` you *probably* want `volume = {22}, number = {5},`. `issue` is for special/seasonal issues like 'Winter', `number` for what is often called 'issue (number)'. You might have to apply a few changes to have the output look like what you have now, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{uniquename}}{0}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\namepartgiven}
       {\namepartprefix}
       {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\namepartgiven}
       {\namepartprefix}
       {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

together with `uniquename=full`, `allfull` or `minfull`.

Normally, even with a `full`-like `uniquename` setting `biblatex` only gives the full name when initials would be ambiguous. With the above we get first names as soon as the last name alone is not enough.

We get the *Last, First* format because we used `name:family-given`; for *First Last* (the default) we'd use `name:given-family`.