# mandatory initials in citations with biblatex authoryear-icomp

Tags: biblatex, citing

I need to have citations in the text to be preceeded by the authors' initials even when initials are not required for disambiguitation. So the call

```
\parencite[244]{kull_geographie_2016}
```

should appear in the text as

> (C. A. KULL et S. BATTERBURY 2016, p. 244)

and in the bibliography as

> KULL, Christian A. et Simon BATTERBURY (2016). « La géographie face aux défis
>   environnementaux dans le monde anglophone ». In : Manifeste pour une géo-
>   graphie environnementale. Presses de Sciences Po, p. 227–255.

==============

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{ThinSpaceInFrenchNumbers=true}
%%% 

\usepackage[backend=biber, style= authoryear-icomp,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
%%%
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[quotes]{french}
  {\itshape\mkfrenchopenquote{\guillemotleft}}
  {\mkfrenchclosequote{\guillemotright}}
  {\itshape\textquotedblleft}
  {\textquotedblright}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Incollection{kull_geographie_2016,
  Title                    = {La géographie face aux défis environnementaux dans
 le monde anglophone},
  Author                   = {Kull, Christian A. and Batterbury, Simon},
  Booktitle                = {Manifeste pour une géographie environnementale},
  Year                     = {2016},
  Edition                  = {Presses de Sciences Po},
  Pages                    = {227--255},
  Collaborator             = {Chartier, Denis and Rodary, Estienne}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document} 

Voila une référence \parencite[244]{kull_geographie_2016}, une autre
\cite[215]{kull_geographie_2016} et encore une autre \textcite{kull_geographie_2016}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did my answer below solve your question? If so, you might want to consider accepting it to show it helped, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. If it did not help I would appreciate a comment explaining why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `labelname` name format. The redefinition below gives initials if they are not ambiguous and full given names if required to disambiguate.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{ThinSpaceInFrenchNumbers=true}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{uniquename}}{2}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\namepartgiven}
       {\namepartprefix}
       {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\ifuseprefix
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffixi}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefixi}
         {\namepartsuffixi}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document} 
Voila une référence \parencite[244]{sigfridsson}, une autre
\cite[215]{sigfridsson} et encore une autre \textcite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352750/35864